# Assign new values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, row

I am trying to change the value in one row in pandas dataframe for certain columns with other values:

```
sub_data.loc[[0],20:71] = sub_data.loc[1,20:71]
or
sub_data.loc[0,20:71] = sub_data.loc[1,20:71]
```

both did not work. any suggestion?

Update

It was solved when I used series

`sub_data.iloc[0,20:71].update(sub_data.iloc[1,20:71])`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
sub_data.loc[[0],20:71] = sub_data.loc[[1],20:71].values
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probable reason is that you are using `20:71` in `loc`.  That looks like you need `iloc`

```
sub_data.iloc[0, 20:71] = sub_data.iloc[1, 20:71]
```

Comment: This works for me on my test data.  You did not provide any details about your data.  Nor did you provide any details about your error.  We can't magically know what happened on your machine without you disclosing more information.  We typically expect a [mcve] to help us understand your problem.  Please consider editing your question in order to provide one.